# PHP - I don't want to use table with loops anymore

Tags: php, mysql

I need to build one table that show all the sales for one day that i've choosen.

I've allways used the dummy way, selecting the table products that had a sale in one day, then do a loop on a php table do get the other informations from others tables.

I wanna know if theres is a simple way getting the data.

**TABLES:**

```
table_products

pr_id | pr_name | pr_price | ..
------|---------|----------|
1     | TV      | 299.99   |
2     | RADIO   |  59.99   |
3     | DVD     |  49.99   |
..    | ..      | ..       |


table_sales

sa_id | sa_coupon | sa_day   | sa_month | ..
------|-----------|----------|----------|
1     | 101       |    4     |    9     |
2     | 102       |    5     |    9     |
3     | 103       |    5     |    9     |
..    | ..        | ..       |..        |
80    | 211       |    2     |    12    |
..    | ..        | ..       |..        |


table_sales_dt

sa_dt_coupon |  sa_dt_product_id      | sa_qtd      |
-------------|------------------------|-------------|..
101      | 1                  | 10          |
101      | 2                  | 5       |
102      | 1              | 5       |
103      | 3              | 8       |
211      | 1              | 15      |
211      | 2              | 10      |
211      | 3              | 5       |
..           | ..             | ..          |
```

i want to show the results like this:

Sales on month 9 (september)

```
N   PRODUCT  QUANTITY    PRICE   TOTAL
1 - TV     - 15       - 299.99 - 4499.85
2 - RADIO  - 5        - 59.99  - 299.95
3 - DVD    - 8        - 49.99  - 399.92
```

THANKS!!!

Comment: Have you tried to use SQL joins?

Comment: Sorry, I can't see the SQL query anywhere of [what you've tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp  the trick is in the sql request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might do it:

```
SELECT p.* FROM table_products p 
LEFT JOIN table_sales_dt dt ON p.id = dt.product_id
LEFT JOIN table_sales s ON dt.sa_dt_coupon = s.sa_coupon
WHERE s.sa_month = 9
```

Comment: Nice, but I want to show only a one product (like SELECT DISTINCT) and their sales total. Like the table above. THANK YOU ANYWAY

Comment: I did, but it take about 50sec to show the results, it's ok or not?